# How to add custom validators to Model Driven Forms

Tags: angular, custom-validators, angular-reactive-forms

Currently i add validators to model driven forms like this

```
password: new FormControl('', [
                Validators.minLength(8),
                Validators.required
            ])
```

what if i want to add custom defined validators
How to do that in model driven forms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write custom form validator (model-driven) that depends on current component's property value in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496816/how-to-write-custom-form-validator-model-driven-that-depends-on-current-compon)

Comment: Thnx fran
i will try that
taking this question down